# How to scale an SVG without losing contours in Easel.js?

Tags: svg, createjs, easeljs

I have an Easel.js-based canvas and a bunch of SVGs. When I put these SVGs on canvas as vector shapes and try to scale the whole canvas, some SVG contours become distorted / blurred.

Are there any ways to avoid such a behavior?

Problem:
[image]

SVG sample:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=88515840051764837348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EaselJS support in canvas is restricted to image-based rendering. Basically, it loads the SVG as a raster image. When you scale it, you aren't seeing it redraw the vector, but instead it scales like an image would. If you scale it above 100% it should be more obvious (it will get pixelly/blurry).

Not sure if you can work around this with an SVG source. You could bring paths into Adobe Animate, and export as raw EaselJS Graphics, which will scale more predictably.

Cheers,

Comment: Wow, that's a pity... I wonder if there're any free software solutions that provide export to Easel.js canvas.